# Tkinter loop "Tkinter não esta respondendo"

Tags: python, loops, tkinter, arduino

I have a code from a tkinter graphical interface that communicates with the arduino, it happens that I get the time that the time turns on and off, so I compare each current time with the typing in an infinite loop that is only for when the second enter code here entry that asks to turn off the led ends, it happens that when it enters in the loop tkinter does not respond.

```
from tkinter import *
import serial
from time import strftime

conexao = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0.5)
cont=0
janela = Tk()
def ligar():
     global cont
     cont=cont+1
     if cont==1:
         valor=bytes(('1'),'utf-8')
         conexao.write(valor)
         ligar['text']='Desligar led'
     elif cont==2:
         valor=bytes(('2'),'utf-8')
         conexao.write(valor)
         ligar['text']='Ligar led'
         cont=0


def agendar():
     comeco= start.get()
     final=  limit.get()
     while 1>0:
          if comeco == strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
               valor=bytes(('1'),'utf-8')
               conexao.write(valor)
          elif final == strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
               valor=bytes(('2'),'utf-8')
               conexao.write(valor)
               break





ligar=Button(janela,command=ligar,text='ligar',width="60")
ligar.grid(row=1)
texto=Label(text='Defina o começo:').grid(row=2)
start=Entry(janela)
start.grid(row=3)
texto2=Label(text='Defina o fim:').grid(row=4)
limit=Entry(janela)
limit.grid(row=5)
salvar=Button(janela,width="30",text='Salvar Horarios',command=agendar)
salvar.grid(row=6)
```

Comment: please post your output

Comment: There are lots of questions on this site related to communicating with an arduino and using tkinter. Have you done any research before asking this question? See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: The code works perfectly, but in the loop the interface hangs and does not modify something else, but it turns on the LEDs as the program asks

Comment: do't use `while` loop but `tkinter.after()` to execute code periodicaly - ti will not block `mainloop()` and IDE will not freeze. BTW: next time instead of `while 1>0:` you can write `while True:`

Comment: how would the part of the while with the after,thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `after` method, you could use threading, which allows for your GUI to be run at the same time as the while loop.

```
import threading
from tkinter import *
import serial
from time import strftime

conexao = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0.5)
cont=0
janela = Tk()
def ligar():
     global cont
     cont=cont+1
     if cont==1:
         valor=bytes(('1'),'utf-8')
         conexao.write(valor)
         ligar['text']='Desligar led'
     elif cont==2:
         valor=bytes(('2'),'utf-8')
         conexao.write(valor)
         ligar['text']='Ligar led'
         cont=0

def agendar():
     global start,limit
     comeco= start.get()
     final=  limit.get()
     while 1>0:
          if comeco == strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
               valor=bytes(('1'),'utf-8')
               conexao.write(valor)
          elif final == strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
               valor=bytes(('2'),'utf-8')
               conexao.write(valor)
               break

global start,limit
ligar=Button(janela,command=ligar,text='ligar',width="60")
ligar.grid(row=1)
texto=Label(text='Defina o começo:').grid(row=2)
start=Entry(janela)
start.grid(row=3)
texto2=Label(text='Defina o fim:').grid(row=4)
limit=Entry(janela)
limit.grid(row=5)
salvar=Button(janela,width="30",text='Salvar Horarios',command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=agendar).start())
salvar.grid(row=6)
```

Here's a short breakdown:

1. Pushing the button executes the lambda function (using the lambda function is useful in that it allows you to avoid a wrapper function)
2. The lambda function creates a separate thread for you agendar function
3. The Thread Starts

*Note: I defined limit and start as global variables, but I'm not sure you need it. 
Also, I have not tested it, but I'm fairly sure it works.*

Comment: Try calling janela.mainloop() at the end. Another thing, you should not use ligar as both the button name and the function name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `after` to run code periodically.

I can't test it but I would do

```
from tkinter import *
import serial
from time import strftime

# -- 
def ligar():
     global cont

     cont = not cont

     if cont:
         conexao.write( b'1' )
         ligar['text'] = 'Desligar led'
     else:
         conexao.write( b'2' )
         ligar['text'] = 'Ligar led'


def agendar():
    comeco = start.get()
    final  = limit.get()

    current = strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    if comeco == current:
        conexao.write( b'1' )
        # run again after 1000ms (1s)
        janela.after(1000, agendar)        
    elif final == current:
        conexao.write( b'2' )

conexao = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=0.5)
cont = False

janela = Tk()

ligar = Button(janela, command=ligar, text='ligar', width="60")
ligar.grid(row=1)

texto = Label(janela, text='Defina o começo:')
texto.grid(row=2)

start = Entry(janela)
start.grid(row=3)

texto2 = Label(janela, text='Defina o fim:')
texto2.grid(row=4)

limit = Entry(janela)
limit.grid(row=5)

salvar = Button(janela, width="30", text='Salvar Horarios', command=agendar)
salvar.grid(row=6)

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: well, in that code it compares only when the button is pressed, not when the condition is true

Comment: In it I have to click at the exact moment the time is equal to the input, it does not compare automatically

Comment: as I said I can't run it to test it.